# Чтение данных с USB.JAVA

Tags: java-ee, applet, java

Всем доброго времени суток!

Есть  [карт-ридер](http://store.acs.com.hk/products/3/acr122u-usb-nfc-reader/smart-card-readers/),который подключается по USB. Необходимо написать аплет, который получал бы данные с определенного USB-порта и вставлял их  в форму на web-страничке.

Собственно,вопрос - не поделитесь инфой по данному вопросу (получению данных с USB) ?

Куда копать, что искать...

Answer (score 1):

Без JNI не обойтись.
Есть библиотеки [Java-USB](http://jusb.sourceforge.net/) и [usb2java](http://usb4java.org/), но говорят они сильно устарели.